# Showing select dropdown after click a button and checking a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show dropdown of select element after clicking on button and when a condition about  some state is true. How can I do that with javascript in react project?

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  if(someState === ''){
     //here code to show dropdown of select element
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<button onClick={handleClick}>Click to show dropdown</button>
```

Comment: We can achieve this by using state also. So why you want to achieve it with js only ?

Comment: @BhartiSharma So how can I do that with state? How can I say react to open my select element after I click on that button and also the condition is true?

Comment: I have one question for clarification that you want to show the dropdown opend on button click and select will be visible bydefault ?

Comment: @BhartiSharma Yes, I do.

Answer (score 0):

I have used mui to achieve the result which you expected without javascript so please check below code :-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
  { value: 'three', label: 'Three' }
];

const DropDownComponent = () => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState('');
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[0].value);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const handler = () => {
    if(someState === ''){
      setIsOpen(true)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        open={isOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onOpen={handleClick}
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <br />
      <br />
      <Button onClick={handler}>Click to show dropdown</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDownComponent;
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: I appreciate you, but I don't use mui, I'm using javascript with react and sass. Do we also have a solution like this with javascript or react? I'm curious to just know if I can do this in javascript and react without any other package or not.